# Radzen DatePicker Font Size

Tags: blazor, font-size, radzen

Radzen has a datepicker for Blazor that looks promising.  The code below displays it on my webassembly blazor page, however, I do not know how to control the font size with the Radzen component.  I have tried adding height to the div, tried adding font-size to the div as well as the RadzenDatePicker style string.  Nothing seems to change the rendered font size.  If I inspect the resulting page.... I see the html that Radzen creates and I can adjust it there but not in my razor page.  Any help appreciated.

```
        <div class="rz-p-0 rz-text-align-center">
            <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value=@value ShowTime="false" HourFormat="12" Style="height:1.5vh;width:30%;" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" />
        </div>

        @code {
            DateTime? value = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

Comment: How I go about customising Radzen components is editing their properties within <style>. I use inspection to find out what CSS style I need to amend.

Comment: Maciek,  thank you for the comment.  This is just what I thought I would try.  What I find is that Radzen creates several nested <div>s during rendering the html and many elements of the style don't cascade down to the inner div where the font-size is.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the values of Radzen. But the css file must be called after the Radzen.Blazor.js in your Layout.cshtml like this:

```css
<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js" />
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Here are some example values you can change, but the easiest thing is to inspect the elements and copy the values.

```css
/*Datepicker-> Changes the fontsize of the date*/
.rz-calendar .rz-inputtext {
   font-size: 20px;
}

/*Popup-> Changes the fontsize of the dropdown selector (Month & Year)*/
.rz-dropdown {
   font-size: 20px;
}

/*Popup-> Changes the fontsize of the days*/
.rz-datepicker-calendar td .rz-state-default {
   font-size: 20px;
}

/*Popup -> Size of the box*/
.rz-datepicker.rz-popup {
   width: 360px !important;
   height: 500px;
}

/*Popup -> Size of the box*/
    .rz-datepicker.rz-popup {
       width: 360px !important;
       height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Off doing some drag and drop code but will circle back and see how this answer works.  
Thanks again!